# Regular Expression in a join using Linq c#?

Tags: c#, mysql, entity-framework, linq

Is it possible to use a regular expressing in a join using linq.

For example:

A Student table contains a field called Subjects with a comma separated value such as "Maths,English,Science".

A Subject table contains a row for each subject having the subject in a Name field.

I want to do an inner join to the Subject table where the Subject Name is in the comma separated value in the Student table.  In MySQL:

```
SELECT st.* 
FROM Student st
INNER JOIN Subjects su ON st.Subjects REGEXP CONCAT('[[:<:]]', su.Name, '[[:>:]]')
```

So in MySQL this should give me all students who have a matching Subject Name in its Subjects field.  Is it possible to do a join such as this in LINQ?

I know that the actual issue is the database design but this isn't something I can change in a hurry.

Thanks, any help appreciated!

Comment: This isn't possible using Entity Framework unless you use a raw SQL query. However... joining with a Regex sounds like a monumentally bad idea in the first place.

Comment: Look at normalising your tables. You should have a table of subjects and a table to store your students-subject values so you remove the many - many relationship which you are avoiding by not making your fields atomic.

Comment: Definitely agree that the database needs normalised. Unfortunately it is an existing database that I have to work with for now but definitely want to make adjustments but just need a quick fix for now.

Comment: It is possible and I have done it plenty of times using a helper method. Will give solution soon.

Comment: What version of EF are you using? Also, your sample query returns nothing of `su` so what is the point?

Answer (score 0):

I did it without Regex.  Instead used string.Split() method

```
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();

            dt.Columns.Add("Subjects", typeof(string));
            dt.Columns.Add("Index", typeof(int));

            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { "Math,English,Science",1 });
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { "English,Science" ,2});
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { "French,Science" ,3});
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { "German,Science" ,4});
            dt.Rows.Add(new object[] { "English,Science" ,5});

            var groups = dt.AsEnumerable().Select(x => new { keys = x.Field<string>("Subjects").Split(new char[] { ',' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries), row = x }).ToArray();
            var rows = groups.Select(x => x.keys.Select(y => new { subject = y, row = x.row })).SelectMany(x => x).ToArray();

            Dictionary<string, List<DataRow>> subjectDict = rows.GroupBy(x => x.subject).ToDictionary(x => x.Key, y => y.Select(z => z.row).ToList());
```

Comment: Hi thanks, although would this not load all rows from the table into memory before doing a split on each row.  Would that not have a big impact on performance?

Comment: No.  The rows are links and not a copy of the rows.  The subject names are strings and my method only keeps distinct values of the string.

Comment: Don't think this solution is necessarily best for EF or LINQ to SQL.

Answer (score 0):

In LINQ, `join` only does equi-join, so if you want to join on other conditions you must emulate the join yourself with `from`...`where`. (Note: I doubt if any indexes will be used by this query.)

```
var ans = from st in Student
          from su in Subjects
          where ("," + st.Subjects + ",").Contains("," + su.Name + ",")
          select new { st, su };
```

If you knew the maximum number of subjects possible, you could emulate `Split` with a fixed number of cases and that would probably use indexes, but at that point you are probably better off using SQL or a stored procedure.

For example, for a maximum of 4 subjects:

```
var ans2 = from st in Student
           let p1 = st.Subjects.IndexOf(",")
           let p2 = (p1 >= 0 ? st.Subjects.Substring(p1 + 1).IndexOf(",") : -1)
           let p3 = (p2 >= 0 ? st.Subjects.Substring(p2 + 1 + p1 + 1).IndexOf(",") : -1)
           let s1 = p1 >= 0 ? st.Subjects.Substring(0, p1) : st.Subjects
           let s2 = p2 >= 0 ? st.Subjects.Substring(p1 + 1, p2) : (p1 >= 0 ? st.Subjects.Substring(p1+1) : "")
           let s3 = p3 >= 0 ? st.Subjects.Substring(p2 + 1 + p1 + 1, p3) : (p2 >= 0 ? st.Subjects.Substring(p2+1+p1+1) : "")
           let s4 = p3 >= 0 ? st.Subjects.Substring(p3+1+p2+1+p1+1) : ""
           from su in Subjects
           where su.Name == s1 || su.Name == s2 || su.Name == s3 || su.Name == s4
           select new { st, su };
```